# How to properly import PermissionsAndroid from react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm actually trying to make use of `react-native-camera`, but I keep running into an error on line 14: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/src/handlePermissions.js#L14 where

```js
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, {
        title: permissionDialogTitle,
        message: permissionDialogMessage,
      });
```

The error I get there is:

```
Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
```

I suspect it's the way `PermissionsAndroid` is imported:

```js
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
```

But `PermissionsAndroid` is `undefined`. Looking at `react-native.js`, I can't find `PermissionsAndroid` anywhere. Has it been moved? I'm on `react-native-cli: 2.0.1`.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html here it is written only for native code

Comment: @RaajNadar I've read that and I think that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Is the above code inside an async function?

Comment: @RaajNadar Yes it is.

Comment: Change the target SDK to 23 if it is lower

Comment: @RaajNadar The target SDK is already 26.

Comment: Check the target SDK in this file `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: @RaajNadar It's already set to 26.

Comment: Try setting target SDK to 22

Comment: IDK if you NEED to prompt user every time but you can put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" /> into your androidmanifest and it should only ask once on install?

Comment: @RaajNadar But is `PermissionsAndroid` supposed to be declared in `react-native.js`?